# Android/iPhone WebView realtime update performance

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I want to make a WebView interface for my app, but it's require some real-time updates to some chart bars. Anyone did that before and have any idea from performance point of view if it's working good? For Android and iPhone/iPad. Rest of the code is made using the standard SDK, but the interface I want to make it HTML5 with JavaScript.

Thanks!

Comment: are u using some service ?? may be then it is possible

Comment: I am not using any services.

Comment: then how is real time ommunication possible?